# Getting error when i load SSH key "Load key "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519": error in libcrypto"

Tags: ssh, git, github

Long story short I have an SSH key pair that I am copying to a new machine from a shared drive whenever the machine starts but when I load in the keys I keep getting an error. There is no difference in operating system between the machine that created the keys and the one that is using them (unsuccessfully).

Load key "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519": error in libcrypto
However when I then create a new SSH keypair it works perfectly fine. Is there some restrictions about copying keys or are they bound to the machine it was created on?

A bit more background is that I am using this to read from my private Github repo,

```
cp [filepath to ssh pub key on shared drive] "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub"
cp [filepath to ssh private key on shared drive] "/root/.ssh/id_ed25519"

ssh-keyscan -t ed25519 github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod go-rwx /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout git@github.com:account/repo.git
```

I have no idea what is going on, and when i print the contents of the two key pairs they are identical, but it seems like the moment a new machine is booted it stops working - any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: the two different `ssh` programs that don't work with each other, what's their version? How did you install them? And: what's the version of libcrypto on your system?

Comment: They came installed with the server - how do I check their version?

Comment: `ssh -V` would work to get the version of SSH, but knowing the operating system / distro you're on would definitely be helpful for figuring out libcrypto

Comment: Thanks I get the following: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Comment: is that true for both machines, the one the key originated from and the one you copied it to?